# C bitwise negation creates negative output:

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I am trying REALLY hard to flip the bits in a C int variable. I am doing it like so:

```
input = 15;

input = ~input;

printf("%d", input);
```

BUT IT ALWAYS SHOWS UP as `-16`. It should be `0`! if `15` is written as `1111`, why is it returning `10000`?! This is maddening! Can somebody PLEASE help me!?

Comment: You forgot the quotation marks on the `%d` format; I've added them.

Comment: It's generally best to copy-and-paste your actual working code; that neatly avoids typos and similar errors.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since `int` on your system is most likely a 32-bit number, all bits are flipped, including the ones that were insignificant zeros in the original number:

```
00000000000000000000000000001111
```

becomes

```
11111111111111111111111111110000
```

This is a negative number: the most significant bit of `15` is zero, so it becomes `1` when flipped.

If you would like to keep only the bits of the original number, you need to mask with all ones in the significant positions of the number, like this:

```
printf("%d\n", input & 0xF);
```

`AND`ing with `0xF` "cuts off" all bits except the last four.

Answer (score 5):

This is occurring because `input` is comprised of more than four bits. If we assume that `input` is a `signed char`, with 8 bits (or one byte), then:

```
input == 15 == 0x0F == 0b00001111
```

As you can see, the 4 more significant bits of `input` are all 0. After a bitwise NOT operation (~), we have:

```
~input == -16 == 0xF0 == 0b11110000
```

The four bits that used to be zero are now ones, and the ones are now zeros. The most significant bit in a signed variable determines its sign (0 being positive and 1 being negative). Thus, by flipping the bits the sign has been reversed. The negative number may be read as:

```
1      1     1     1     0     0     0   0
-128 + 64  + 32  + 16  + 0   + 0   + 0 + 0
```

which resolves to the -16 that was printed.

If your homework is to zero a variable using the bitwise NOT, try declaring `input` as an `unsigned char` to avoid having to worry about the sign bit. Then, set `input` to `255`, the highest value an 8 bit variable can hold (`0xFF` or `0b11111111`).

Answer (score 3):

`15` is of type `int`. Depending on how big `int` is, the representation of `15` ends in `1111`, but it *starts* with a bunch of `0`s.

The `~` operator flips *all* the bits; the `1`s (4 of them) become `0`s, and the `0`s (N-4 of them) become `1`s.