# Why does the following bitwise operation return an unintended result?

Tags: c

3 bits can hold up to a maximum number of 7 (4 + 2 + 1).  I'm trying to calculate this using a bitwise operation.

```
3 is 0b011 
~3 is 0b100
```

Doing a bitwise OR I would expect 0b111 (i.e. 7).  Instead I get

```
int result = (~3) | 3;
printf("%i\n", result);
```

> -1

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C bitwise negation creates negative output:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084364/c-bitwise-negation-creates-negative-output)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are doing everything right: `N | ~N` results in a number with binary representation consisting of all ones. Such number is interpreted as `-1` in [two's compliment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation of negative numbers.

Comment: Yeah never mind, I just realized I was wrong and deleted the comment before you posted that comment.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue `~3` is `111111..111100`, so the last three bits are indeed `0b100`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight `3` is an integer literal of type `int`. The `~` operator isn't well defined for signed integers.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue: The bit-pattern of ~ is perfectly well defined for signed integers; it is each bit inverted.  The interpretation of that value depends on whether the integers are one's complement, two's complement or sign and magnitude, but the same was true of the interpretation of the value of the integer before inversion.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Please show me where the standard says that the sign bit is to be inverted...

Comment: @Undefined, 6.5.3.3/4 says "each bit in the result is set if and only if the corresponding bit in the converted operand is not set." Surely, the sign bit is part of the operand, no?

Answer (score 4):

How many bits wide is an `int`? You seem to think it's three bits wide. Certainly not correct! Guess again. What is `~0u`? Try `printf("%u\n", ~0u);`. What about `~1u`? ... and `~2u`? Do you notice a pattern?

Note the `u` suffix, which tells the compiler that it's an `unsigned` literal. You can't work with signed integer types with the `~` operator... Well, you *can*, but you might run into trap representations and negative zeros, according to 6.2.6.2 of n1570.pdf. Using a trap representation is undefined behaviour. That *might* work on your system, but only by coincidence. Do you want to rely upon coincidence?

Similarly, I suggest using the `%u` directive to print `unsigned` values, as `%d` would produce undefined behaviour according to 7.21.6.1p29 of n1570.pdf.

Comment: @Jueecy.new Can you use questions to teach people/answer other questions? Read [The Socratic Method](http://www.garlikov.com/Soc_Meth.html).

Comment: [Nice question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177612/should-the-socratic-method-be-discouraged).

Answer (score 0):

When you do `~3` you are inverting the bits that make up 3 - so you turn `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0011` into `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1100`. Since the high bit is set, this is interpreted as a negative number - all 1s is -1, one less than that is -2, one less -3 and so on. This number is the signed 32 bit integer for -4.

If you binary OR this with 3, you get all 1s (by definition) - which is the signed 32 bit integer for -1.

Your only problem is that you think you are working with 3 bit numbers, but you are actually working with 32 bit numbers.

Answer (score 0):

After doing this in the code

```
  int result = (~3) | 3;
```

Add this line

```
   result= result & 0x07
```

This will give you the answer that you expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
    unsigned d3 = 0b011;
    unsigned invd3 = ~d3;
    unsigned d4 = 0b100;
    unsigned result = d3 | invd3;
    printf("%X\n", result);//FFFFFFFF
    result = d3 | d4;
    printf("%X\n", result);//7
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to add some description with this answer ;-)

Comment: @SandipArmalPatil I don't think necessary.