# Understanding the bitwise negation of signed numbers and negative number representation in a typical sysem

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

Suppose I have a signed char member `num = 15` and I do `num = ~num`. Then, as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084364/c-bitwise-negation-creates-negative-output) post, we will get -16.

```
~(00001111) = (11110000)
```

But, if I consider the MSB as sign bit, shouldn't the answer be `-112`? How come this is resulting in -16? Why the second and third set bits from left are being ignored.

Can anyone please clarify.

**EDIT**
I want more detailed explaination of why the following program resulted in -16 and not -112

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char num = 15;
    num = ~num;

    printf("%d\n", num);
    return 0;
}
```

I expected it as `1(1110000) = -(1110000) = -112`

Comment: In 2's complement the other bits beside the sign bit have the same meaning in both positive and negative;  `11110000` is `-128 + 64 + 32 + 16` giving `-16`

Comment: The "sign bit" is not the "minus bit". Consider that adding 16 to it (as a raw bit pattern, disregard any meaning) results in 0, therefore it must have been -16 to begin with.

Comment: you are mixing 1's compliment and signed bits. you should do 2's compliment.

Answer (score 3):

`~(00001111) = (11110000)`

What you're doing is using the MSb (Most Significant bit) as a flag to decide to put a '-' sign, and then reading the rest of the bits normally. Instead, the MSb is a flag to do *2* things: put a '-' sign - and then NOT the value and add one (2's complement) - before printing out the rest of the bits.

This comes from the overflow/underflow nature of fixed-length bit values:

```
00000010 - 1 = 00000001 (2-1=1)
00000001 - 1 = 00000000 (1-1=0)
00000000 - 1 = 11111111 (0-1=-1)
```

Answer (score 3):

C allows for three different representations of signed integers, but the most common is "two's complement". However, I'll briefly discuss "one's complement" as well to illustrate how there is a relationship between them.

### One's complement

One's complement integers are split into sign and value bits. To use the 8-bit representation of the integer `19` as an example:

```
S|64 32 16  8  4  2  1
0| 0  0  1  0  0  1  1 = 19
```

Using the bitwise complement operator `~` flips all of the bits of the integer, including the sign bit:

```
S|64 32 16  8  4  2  1
1| 1  1  0  1  1  0  0 = ~19
```

When the sign bit is set, the interpretation of 1 and 0 bits is reversed (0=on, 1=off), and the value is considered negative. This means the value above is:

```
-(16 + 2 + 1) = -19
```

### Two's complement

Unlike one's complement, an integer is not divided into a sign bit and value bits. Instead, what is regarded as a sign bit adds `-2^(b - 1)` to the rest of the value, where `b` is the number of bits. To use the example of an 8-bit representation of `~19` again:

```
-128 64 32 16  8  4  2  1
   1  1  1  0  1  1  0  0 = ~19

  -128 + 64 + 32 + 8 + 4
= -128 + 108
= -(128 - 108)
= -20
```

### The relationship between them

The value of `-19` is 1 more than `-20` arithmetically, and this follows a generic pattern in which any value of `-n` in two's complement is always one more than the value of `~n`, meaning the following always holds true for a value `n`:

```
-n = ~n + 1
~n = -n - 1 = -(n + 1)
```

This means that you can simply look at the 5-bit value `15`, negate it and subtract 1 to get `~15`:

```
~15 = (-(15) - 1)
    = -16
```

`-16` for a 5-bit value in two's complement is represented as:

```
-16 8 4 2 1
  1 0 0 0 0 = -16
```

Flipping the bits using the `~` operator yields the original value `15`:

```
-16 8 4 2 1
  0 1 1 1 1 = ~(-16) = -(-16 + 1) = -(-15) = 15
```

### Restrictions

I feel I should mention arithmetic overflow regarding two's complement. I'll use the example of a 2-bit signed integer to illustrate. There are 2^2=4 values for a 2-bit signed integer: -2, -1, 0, and 1. If you attempt to negate `-2`, it won't work:

```
-2 1
 1 0 = -2
```

Writing `+2` in plain binary yields `1 0`, the same as the representation of `-2` above. Because of this, `+2` is not possible for a 2-bit signed integer. Using the equations above also reveals the same issue:

```
// Flip the bits to obtain the value of ~(-2)
~(-2) = -(-2 + 1)
~(-2) = 1

// Substitute 1 in place of ~(-2) to find the result of -(-2)
-(-2) = ~(-2) + 1
-(-2) = 1 + 1
-(-2) = 2
```

While this makes sense mathematically, the fact is that 2 is outside the representable range of values (only -2, -1, 0, and 1 are allowed). That is, adding 1 to 01 (1) results in 10 (-2). There's no way to magically add an extra bit in hardware to yield a new sign bit position, so instead you get an arithmetic overflow.

In more general terms, you cannot negate an integer in which only the sign bit is set with a two's complement representation of signed integers. On the other hand, you cannot even represent a value like -2 in a 2-bit one's complement representation because you only have a sign bit, and the other bit represents the value `1`; you can only represent the values `-1, -0, +0, and +1` with one's complement.